# What is the right way to hold and restore the data temporarily between activities in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharedpreferences

I am creating an Android app. One of the functions is to collect some data (item name, item ID and the barcode string) from the user .

Activity1 is a form. User enters the item name and item number manually. For the barcode string, user clicks on the "scan" button then Activity2 (Scanner) is started in order to scan and read the barcode. Once the barcode is read, Activity1 (the form) starts again and all data should appear on the form.

When Activity2 starts by Intent, Activity1 is killed. So, I have to get the item name and item number and store them temporarily before staring the Intent. Then when Activity1 starts again, those data will be rendered on the form again.

Now I am thinking to use Intent Extra to keep the item name and number, and pass them to Activity2 and back to Activity1. Given that Activity2 doesn't need those data, I wonder if that is the right way to do in this scenario.  Is there any better way? Should I use Shared Preferences instead?

Comment: *When Activity2 starts by Intent, Activity1 is killed.* only if you explicitly destroy it. Is that the case? If so, why?

Comment: @MLAC regarding the question: you don't need to worry. The first activity is never killed. You can use the normal save/restore instance state mechanic to keep the information you need around (Google "restore instance state" if you don't know what I'm taking about).

Comment: The problem i have now is that when i use intent to go from Activity1 to Activity2,  Activity1 and the data on the form are gone.  So, when I launch Activity1 again, the activity is created without the previous data. So I have to save the data before starting Activity2.

Comment: How are you returning to `Activity1` from `Activity2`? It shouldn't "start again", it should just resume. In that case, all the data in the form should still be there. Please add your manifest to your post.

Comment: Also, if `Activity2` doesn't need the data you collect in `Activity1`, there is no reason to pass this data to `Activity2`.

Answer (score 0):

In Your first activity use `put extra` argument to intent like this:

```
// Assuming Activity2.class is second activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class); 
intent.putExtra("variable_name", var); // here you are passing var to second activity
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in second activity retrieve argument like this:

```
String var2 = getIntent().getStringExtra(variable_name);
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing now: using Intent Extra (i.e. .putExtra) to carry the data around.  or Should I use "Shared Preferences" to hold the data in the local file temporarily? I wonder if Shared Preferences would be a better way. For Shared Preferences, local storage is required through...

Comment: Using putExtra you can store data for one cycle only i.e. When you exit the Application, your stored data will be lost. But in case of Shared Preferences you can even reterived data even after you exit Application and again open the Application. Shared Preferences is used place of SQLite when small amount of data is needed to store.

Comment: In your use-case I would suggest to use Shared Preferences.

Comment: In your use-case if it is required to retain data even after Application exit then Shared Preferences is a good option. If it is not required to store data after application exit then putExtra is better because it is faster and optimized.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a singleton class and expose setter(for saving) and getter (for retrieving) methods for the model objects (here two private string variables).This class will be alive with your application:

```
public class MyClass{
private static MyClass instance=null;
public static getInstance(){
if(instance==null){
instance=new MyClass();
}
return instance;
}


private String itemName;
private String itemNumber;
//setter and getter methods here  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why need to kill the Activity 1, try to call

on Activity 1

declare `private int SCAN_BARCODE_REQUEST = 101;`

and then

```
 //finish();  dont use this to destroy activity 1
 startActivityForResult(new intent(this,Activity2.class), SCAN_BARCODE_REQUEST);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == SCAN_BARCODE_REQUEST) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String barcode = data.getStringExtra("BARCODE");

             //handle your barcode string here
        }
    }
}
```

on your Activity 2, 
change your start Activity1 with

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("BARCODE", barcodeString);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use `SharedPreferences`.
You can learn how to use them here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

`SharedPreferences` is a really good solution for such applications. It is very simple and easy to use and implement.

Comment: He knows he can use sharedpreferences. Why would you recommend that? Why not send back data in an intent and use activity results?

Comment: That will be an unnecessary waste of memory to create so many variables., because he wants to come back to Activity1 and load the data again. That wwill require 2 intents. to send data from Activity1 to Activity2 and another one from Activity2 to Activity1. It will create necessary threads and waste memory. `SharedPreferences` is easier and lighter on the machine.

Comment: And you think that writing/reading sharedpreferences, which are stored in a file on disk, is faster than adding a data field to an intent?

Comment: I am trying to figure out which one is better: 1. use "Intent Extra" to carry the  data around, or 2. use "Shared Preferences" to hold the data in the local file.... I'm using "1" now, and I wonder if "2" would be a better way. For "1", no local storage is required...

Comment: @MLAC sharedpreferences is definitely not the best solution for this case

Comment: @MLAC use startActivityForResult() with bundle

Comment: @SanathKashyap What makes you think that passing data as "extras" in an `Intent` between 2 activities "creates threads and waste memory"? That's just nonsense.